# rails7でbin/devをするとzsh: no such file or directory: bin/devになってしまう。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

#### 前提

```
% ruby -v
ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x86_64-darwin21]

% rails -v
Rails 7.0.3

% which ruby
/Users/t-k/.rbenv/shims/ruby

% ls bin
bundle      importmap   rails       rake        setup
```

Ruby on Rails初学者です。
Rails7でアプリをnewしたあとに、bin/devコマンドでサーバーを立ち上げて確認しようとしたところ、下記エラーが出てしまい前に進むことができません。

```
% bin/dev
zsh: no such file or directory: bin/dev
```

これまで通り、rails sコマンドをするとサーバーが立ち上がります。
しかし、ウェブでRails7のアップデート情報をチェックしていると
**「Rails7アップデート後は、サーバーは【rails s】ではなく【bin/dev】で立ち上げてね。」**
との情報がありました。
しかし、**私の環境下ではbin/devではサーバーの立ち上げができません。**

なぜ、みなさんと違う挙動なのでしょうか。
どうか教えていただけますと助かります。

質問者の理解レベル
・これまではRails6でアプリ開発を進めており、一通りアプリを作れるレベル
・環境構築系の話は一切分かっていない
・rails sでひとまずサーバーを立ち上げられる

#### 実現したいこと

- bin/devでサーバーを立ち上げる

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
% bin/dev
zsh: no such file or directory: bin/dev
```

#### 参考にしたサイト

[Rails 7.0 + Ruby 3.1でゼロからアプリを作ってみたときにハマったところあれこれ](https://qiita.com/jnchito/items/5c41a7031404c313da1f#bindev-%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%81%A7%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%82%92%E8%B5%B7%E5%8B%95%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bootstrapを指定してRailsアプリをnewしてみましたが、bin/devはありますね。
Railsアプリ構築の手順に問題があるのでは？

```
/tmp/app $ ls bin 
bundle*   dev*   rails*  rake*   setup*

/tmp/app $ bin/dev
11:23:57 web.1  | started with pid 5587
11:23:57 js.1   | started with pid 5588
11:23:57 css.1  | started with pid 5589
11:23:57 js.1   | yarn run v1.22.19
11:23:57 css.1  | yarn run v1.22.19
11:23:57 js.1   | $ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets --watch
11:23:57 css.1  | $ sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules --watch
11:23:58 js.1   | [watch] build finished, watching for changes...
11:23:58 web.1  | => Booting Puma
11:23:58 web.1  | => Rails 7.0.3 application starting in development 
11:23:58 web.1  | => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
11:23:58 web.1  | Puma starting in single mode...
11:23:58 web.1  | * Puma version: 5.6.4 (ruby 3.1.2-p20) ("Birdie's Version")
11:23:58 web.1  | *  Min threads: 5
11:23:58 web.1  | *  Max threads: 5
11:23:58 web.1  | *  Environment: development
11:23:58 web.1  | *          PID: 5587
11:23:58 web.1  | * Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
11:23:58 web.1  | * Listening on http://[::1]:3000
11:23:58 web.1  | Use Ctrl-C to stop
11:23:58 css.1  | Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
11:23:58 css.1  |
```

Answer (score 0):

調べた範囲では、`jsbundling-rails`のような新しいJS管理の方法で`rails new`したときにのみ、`bin/dev`がインストールされるようです。Rails本体には`bin/dev`を生成するコードが見当たりませんでした。

もし`webpacker`などを使っている場合、単に`rails s`すれば問題ないと思われます。